# how to add xAxis.tick dynamically

Tags: highcharts

I'm coding a dynamic chart (a monitor app) which xAxis is datetime type, every three seconds I pull data from DB and add new point for each serie (so far so good). The problem comes with tick, every time I add a new point all ticks take the current time instead of keeping their original value when they were created this is my code

```
var chart1Obj = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'welcome-chart',
            type: 'line',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            // marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series;
                    setInterval(function () {
                        Meteor.call("getGraphData", function (error, json) {
                            if (error) {
                                console.error("Welcome.graphData() failed\n", error);
                            } else {
                                temp = JSON.parse(json);
                                series[0].addPoint([temp.running], true, true);
                                series[1].addPoint([temp.queued], true, true);
                                series[2].addPoint([temp.suspended], true, true);
                            }
                        });
                    }, 3000);
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Job monitoring'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150,
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    var myTime = new Date();
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', myTime.getTime());
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Number of Task'
            },
            floor: 0,
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
                }]
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Running',
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            width: 1,
            color: '#00FF00'
        }, {
            name: 'Queued',
            width: 2,
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            color: '#FFFF00'
        }, {
            name: 'Suspended',
            width: 3,
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            color: '#FF0000'
        }]
    };

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false,
        }
    });
    var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(chart1Obj);
```

so the question is, what am I doing wrong? or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by this lines:

```
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                var myTime = new Date();
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', myTime.getTime());
            }
        }
```

`new Date()` will create date object with **actual time**. Then you use that date for each label in tick labels. simply use:

```
return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.value);
```

Comment: it didn't work, now it prompt 19:00:00 for each tick regardless of what time it is. this is how it was before and the reason why I added those line for new Date()

Comment: But whyyy `new Date()` ? It always return actual time.. I think the problem is that you have data like this: `data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` - where each point has timestamp (for day) increased by 1ms..

Comment: ok, that kind of make sense, the only reason why I did this "[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]" was to create 20 x ticks, how would you initialize this chart????

Comment: Instead of `0` use `[some_timestamp, 0]`.